# Best way to redirect entire folder of content in Umbraco

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco7

We're going to be redeveloping a large site (12K+ pages, 300K uniques per month). Plan is to use Umbraco 7 in a load balanced scenario.

However, on the old site we have a lot of content such as:
www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/brown-fox.aspx

In the new site we're thinking of changing the structure somewhat to something like:
www.example.com/folder1/brown-fox.aspx

So what would be the best way to redirect entire folder paths? The end of the Url (brown-fox.aspx) will stay the same, just the folder structure.

I know I could add a URL Rewrite rule for each page but that would be very unmanageable very quickly and with that many potential redirects I'm worried about performance.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the [URL Rewrite Module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is the best option for situations like these. It's fast and powerful.

I think what you're looking for is something like this in your web config. You would then create a similar rule for each group of folders that need redirecting.

```
<rule name="New Folder Structure" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder1/folder2/folder3/(.*\.aspx)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/folder1/{R:1}" 
        appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Alternatively, if you don't intend to serve anything deeper than `/folder1/`, you can have one rule to... rule them all...

```
    <rule name="New Folder Structure" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^folder1/(.*)/(.*\.aspx)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/folder1/{R:2}"
          appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Full examples etc. can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: Great thanks! To be honest I forgot about the IIS rewrite module - I was focusing too much on an Umbraco solution.